# fully-buffered stream get flushed when it is not full

Tags: c, buffer

I really confused with how exactly a buffer work. So I write a little snippet to verify:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1024 

char buf[BUF_SIZE];
char arr[20];

int main()
{
        FILE* fs=fopen("test.txt","r");
        setvbuf(fs,buf,_IOFBF,1024);
        fread(arr,1,1,fs);
        printf("%s",arr);

        getchar();

        return 0;
}
```

As you see, I set the file stream `fs` to `fully buffered` stream(I know most of the time it would default to fully-buffered. just making sure). And I also set its related buffer to be size `1024`, which mean that the stream would not be flushed until it contain 1024 bytes of stuff(right?).

In my opinion, the routine of `fread()` is that, it read data from the file stream, store it at its buffer `buf`,and then the data in the `buf` would be send to the `arr` as soon as it is full of 1024 bytes of data(right?).

But now, I read only one character from the stream!!And also, there is are only four characters in the file `test.txt`. why can I find something in the `arr` in case that there is only one char(I can print that one character out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinctions between fully-buffered, line-buffered, and unbuffered really only matter for output streams.  I'm pretty sure that input streams are pretty much always act like they're fully buffered.

But even for fully-buffered input streams, there's at least one case where the buffer won't be fully full, and as you've discovered, that's where there aren't enough characters left in the input to fill the buffer.  If there are only 4 characters in the file, then when the system goes to fill the buffer, it gets those 4 characters and puts them in the buffer, and then you can start taking them out, as usual.

(The same situation would arise any time the file contains a number of characters that's not an exact multiple of the buffer size.  For example, if the input file contained 1028 characters, then after filling the buffer with the first 1024 characters and letting you read them, the next time it filled the buffer, it'd end up with 4 again.)

What were you expecting it to do in this case?  Block waiting to read 1,020 more characters from the file (that were never going to come)?

P.S. You said "the stream would not be flushed until it contained 1024 bytes of stuff, right?"  But flushing is only defined for *output* streams; it doesn't mean anything for input streams.

Comment: Are you sure that flush mean only for output stream, not input stream?

Comment: I just want to verify my guess. According to my understanding, I guess if there is not enough character to fill a buffer of fully-buffer stream, then the content in the buffer cannot be read. But obviously it is wrong

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about `fflush` on input streams!  See [this entry](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/l).

Comment: Pretty agree with your answer. But, by the way, what does `flush` do when you flush a output stream? Does the can only be used after you have flushed it? If not, why do we use flush?

Comment: @walkerlala: Not quite sure what you're asking, but: when you write characters to a buffered output stream, the characters start filling up the buffer, and the buffer actually gets written to the final output (a) when it fills up or (b) when you write a newline if it's line-buffered or (c) immediately if it's unbuffered or (d) when you close the stream or (e) when you call `fflush`. For input streams, you read from the buffer, and if when you try to read the buffer is empty the system tries to fill it.  If it's partly full that's fine, if it can't fill it at all that's EOF.

Comment: totally understand now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, an input buffer works different to what you suggested: if you request one Byte to be read, the system reads 1023 more Bytes into the buffer, so on the next 1023 subsequent read calls it can return data directly from the buffer instead of having to read from the file.

Comment: But what if there is not enough character in the file to be read? My file contain only four characters

Comment: I would guess that only 4 Bytes are read into the buffer then. Maybe investigating the contents of your buffer after each read (and trying this for different read/buffer/file sizes) can help you get more insights into the behavior of this system.

Comment: actually my opinion of how a buffer work is like your, that is, the buffer related to the stream are full with data from the file before any I/O operation occur.

Comment: Or, to be more specific, a a buffer of fully-buffered stream is always filled with data from the file automatically. if one character get read out, then another would come in...and for line-buffered stream, its buffer are filled with data from the stream up to the first newline character

Comment: @walkerlala it isn't. The buffer is filled on the first read, to the extent possible, in fact every time it is empty.

Comment: then what does it mean when we "flush a stream"?

Comment: For an _output_ stream, `fflush` means "write the buffer to the output right now, even though the buffer isn't full yet".  For an input stream, however, `fflush` doesn't mean anything.